# Titles should be side-by-side in side-by-side markdown view

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list

If you look at [a revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2267/revisions) in side-by-side view, the titles are, as you would expect, side-by-side:

[image]

If, however, you look at it in side-by-side markdown view, the titles cease to be side-by-side:

[image]

I think it would make more sense if titles were side-by-side in both side-by-side view and in side-by-side markdown view.